# Power dissipated is maximum or minimum when step up transformer is used

Tags: alternator

> The large scale transmission and distribution of electrical energy over long distances is done with the use of transformers. The voltage output of the generator is stepped-up (so that current is reduced and consequently, the \$I^2 R\$ loss is cut down). It is then transmitted over long distances to an area sub-station near the consumers. There the voltage is stepped down.

Here is what it looks wrong to me. If voltage is increased (stepped up) to decrease current \$I\$ so that power loss \$P=I^2R\$ is minimum. But doesn’t that mean power loss is maximum because \$P=\dfrac{V^2}{R}\$

[sorry for bad english]

Comment: Use `\$` for MathJAX on this site. I've done it for you.

Answer (score 1):

No, the (resistive) power loss in an energy distribution system is proportional to current, not voltage. That's because the resistance of the wire, where the loss occurs, is in series with the load, and not in parallel with it. The wire resistance never "sees" the full line voltage across it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRcvo7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I was looking for 11-12th grade level answer. (Btw that might be useful for future visitors)

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked dozens of times already.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVD13O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Both power supplies are supplying 1000 W but at different voltages.*

In Figure 1a the transmission losses will be in RT. Total line and load resistance is  10 Ω. At 100 V the current will be 10 A. Since the line resistance is 1 Ω then 1/10 of the power (100 W) will be lost in the line resistance.

In Figure 1b the total line and load resistance is 1000 Ω but now, since the load resistance is increased by the square of the voltage ratios (with a little fudging to keep the calculations simple) the current has dropped to 1 A and the line losses are 1 A x 1 Ω = 1 W = 1% of the low voltage option.

Your basic mistake is to look at the load voltage. You should be looking at the voltage drop along the line.